# CSS absolute positioning, what is "non-statically positioned ancestor"?

Tags: html, css, positioning

So I have been following [this tutorial](http://designshack.net/articles/css/the-lowdown-on-absolute-vs-relative-positioning/), to get a more clear understanding of relative and absolute positioning . Most of the things are clear but towards the end of the article it says
about absolute positioning .

> ..it doesn’t always default to the top left of the browser window.
>   Instead, what position: absolute; really does is position the element
>   relative to its **first non-statically-positioned ancestor** (inherit
>   doesn’t count either)...

Can someone put that in layman's terms please.
Thanks

Comment: This might be a bit of a dry read, but does explain everything, including what a "positioned element" is. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not statically positioned element is an element having `position` property set to anything other than `static` *(which is the default value)*.

For e.g: `position: relative || absolute || fixed`

If no such positioned ancestor is found, the `absolute` positioned element will be positioned relative to the window.